# HAProxy timeout keep-alive vs timeout client

Tags: haproxy, keep-alive

I try to configure keep-alive connection for HAProxy. However, HAProxy terminates the connection after some timeout which is based on my tries is: min of (timeout keep-aliv, timeout client)

Here is the config:

```
defaults
   log     global
   mode    http
   option  httplog
   option  dontlognull
   option  persist
   option  redispatch
   option  forwardfor

   option  http-keep-alive
   timeout connect 5s
   timeout check   5s
   timeout client  31s
   timeout server  600s
   timeout http-keep-alive 300s
```

With this configuration tcpdump shows that HAProxy sends FIN, ACK after 31s to client. If I change http-keep-alive to 20s then FIN, ACK will be send after 20s. 
Basically, it's unclear to me how better to configure HAProxy to use high keep alive timeout.

Comment: I see the same behaviour on v2.4.18. If you don't define http-keep-alive, it uses the same value as timeout client.